# How can modbus be partially corrupted?

Tags: modbus, minimalmodbus

I have a modbus slave from which I am receiving what appears to be partially corrupted responses. I have confirmed that the communications are good under some circumstances. In others, I get a checksum error.

If send the command `01 04 00 05 00 01 21 CB`, where 04 is read input register and 05 is the address, three times I get back `F8 9E 01 04 02 00 97`, `B8 9A 01 04 02 00 92`, and `38 9D 01 04 02 00 93`. Since the `01 04 02 00` is consistent each time, it seems like the signal isn't totally trashed, but the first two bytes are apparently causing the checksum to fail.

What problems cause this behavior?

I'm using the python [minimalmodbus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MinimalModbus/) library on a Raspberry Pi.

*Editorial note: I posted this to SO because it has [all of the modbus questions on the SE network](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=modbus) but if someone can think of a better place for it I'm open to moving it*

Comment: The first thing I would do is set up a separate serial monitor on the serial port (using something like realterm) and verify exactly what is going out and what is coming back.  You can use a USB-RS485 or USB-RS232 converter if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Are you communicating over a serial line? I have seen noisy or improperly terminated modbus serial lines cause phantom values to appear either before or after a valid query and response.

While the specifics change depending on the details of your setup (number of wires, baudrate, topology of serial link, etc...), the general rule is to place a 120ohm resister between the wires at each end of the serial link.

Comment: I don't have terminating resistors because I didn't think you needed them for a single slave system. Is this mistaken?

Comment: Terminating resistors are used to mitigate impedance mismatch in the wires, and are generally used at extreme ends of the bus. I have heard of terminating resistors being used at each device drop off the bus, but in my experience, placing them at both ends is sufficient.

Comment: impedance mismatch can cause distortion in serial comms w/ a long length of wire, or at high baud rates, or both. If you run at a slow baud rate and on a short line, the impedance mismatch is likely to NOT cause any problems. I have consistently been able to communicate with devices at 19200bps on a link about 5-10ft in length w/o terminating resistors, so terminating resistors may or may not be your issue. It largely depends on the RS-485 hardware you are using at either end, as well as the type of wire, length of the communications line, and baudrate.

Comment: One other thing to consider, what type of serial drivers are you using? RS-232? RS-485? Just coming directly off of the Raspberry Pi straight to the modbus device? Because in my experience terminating resistors are generally only used on RS-485.

Comment: Thanks for the info on terminating resistors. We're running RS-485 lines, and using an FTDI RS-485 to USB converter, and reading/writing from the USB port on the Pi.

Comment: If you've got the terminating resistors in, and still getting errors, I have a couple more guesses: First, it could be due to the receiver being on while your transmitting, which might place some garbage data in your buffer queue. This is a guess on my part, but look over how you've got your serial port configured and see if you can put it in a mode where the receiver is disabled while transmitting.

Comment: Also, the RS-485 wires can drift when both sides are in an idle state. Sometimes bias resistors are used to pull the idle bus into a known level when the bus is idle. Some ports have internal circuitry to do this automatically, but some may require bias resistors to avoid noise on the line when idle. Check your specs on your FTDI USB->RS-485 converter to see what they recommend.

Comment: [Texas Instruments](https://www.ni.com/support/serial/resinfo.htm) has a pretty good guide on resistors for termination and biasing on RS-485. This is what I would try next.